# What is CSS constant() used for?

Tags: css

Besides `var()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and `env()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env) it seems that CSS also supports `constant()`. I could not find anything on MDN about it and I'm interested to know what it's used for.

Comment: What is your source for `constant` existing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe `constant()` was a precursor to `env()` in the draft spec for environmental variables. You should just use env moving forward and disregard constant.

https://caniuse.com/css-env-function
[image]

---

I found these notes from the initial spec:

### User Agent Properties

This specification defines an open-ended set of properties called User Agent properties, which, among other things, are used to define the substitution
value of constant() functions.

Name: (various)
Value: 
Initial: (nothing, see prose)
Applies to: all elements
Inherited: yes
Percentages: n/a
Media: all
Computed value: specified value with variables substituted (but see prose for "invalid variables")
Canonical order: per grammar
Animatable: no

A User Agent property is not specified in a style sheet. User Agent properties instead define variables, referenced with the constant() notation.

For example, a page that wants to use the user's requested font sizing, and page

**background:**

```
:root {
  font-size: constant(user-font-size);
}

body {
  background-color: constant(user-background-color);
}
```

Unlike other CSS properties, User Agent property names are case-sensitive.

User Agent properties are not reset by the all property. If a style rule attempts to
define a value for a User Agent property, it is ignored.
Using Cascading User Agent Variables: the 'constant()' notation

The value of a User Agent property can be substituted into the value of another
property with the constant() function. The syntax of constant() is:

```
constant() = constant( <user-agent-property-name> [, <declaration-value> ]? )
```

The constant() function is used in the same manner, and follows the same rules,
as the var() function.

Source: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1693